# How to change text label in wicket

Tags: wicket

I'm trying to change the text on a button in wicket using AjaxLink but it is not working, any help please? here is my code;

```
<form name="depForm" wicket:id="depSummaryForm" action=""> 
<div class="uw_summary"> <div class="buttonContainer"> 
<span class="button_v2" wicket:id="newRecruitContainer"> 
<button class="internal_button" wicket:id="newRecruitEWLButton" 
type="button"> Create New Recruit EWL </button> </span> 

final WebMarkupContainer newRecruitContainer = new 
WebMarkupContainer("newRecruitContainer")
{
Label buttonlabel = new Label("newRecruitEWLButton", Model.of(" "));
buttonlabel.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);

AjaxLink newRecruitEWLButton = new AjaxLink("newRecruitEWLButton") { 
@Override public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) { 
buttonlabel.setDefaultModelObject(Model.of("Creating EWL")); 
target.add(buttonlabel); boolean isWorkItemCreated = 
NewRecruitEWLUtil.createNewRecruitWorkItem(appInfo); } };
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the Label's model, not to add a new Label.

```
WebMarkupContainer xyzContainer = new WebMarkupContainer("xyzContainer") {

   @Override
   public void onConfigure() {  // [1]
      super.onConfigure();
      boolean isVisible = some code goes here
      setVisible(isVisible);
   }
};

final Label buttonlabel = new Label("clickMe", ""); // [2]
buttonlabel.setOutputMarkupId(true); // [3]

AjaxLink xyzButton = new AjaxLink("xyzButton") {
   @Override
   public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {         
       buttonlabel.setModelObject("Clicked")); // [4]
       target.add(buttonlabel);
   }
};


xyzContainer.add(xyzButton);
Form.add(xyzContainer);
```

Here are my suggested changes:

1. Use onConfigure() + setVisible() because isVisible() is called many times and depending on how expensive is "some code goes here" it may affect the overall performance
2. Sets an initial label - empty string
3. setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag() should be used when the Component could be set to invisible. If it is always visible then setOutputMarkupId(true) is enough
4. Use Component.setModelObject(...) to set a new value of the same Label instance

Update:
Here is how your code should look like:

```
<form name="depForm" wicket:id="depSummaryForm"> 
   <div class="uw_summary"> 
     <div class="buttonContainer"> 
       <span class="button_v2" wicket:id="newRecruitContainer"> 
         <button class="internal_button" wicket:id="newRecruitEWLButton" 
type="button">
 <span wicket:id="label">Create New Recruit EWL</span></button> 
       </span>
     </div>
   </div>
</form>


final WebMarkupContainer newRecruitContainer = new 
WebMarkupContainer("newRecruitContainer");

Label buttonlabel = new Label("label", Model.of(" "));
   buttonlabel.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);

   AjaxLink newRecruitEWLButton = new AjaxLink("newRecruitEWLButton") 
   { 
      @Override public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) { 
          buttonlabel.setDefaultModelObject(Model.of("Creating EWL")); 
          target.add(buttonlabel); 
          boolean isWorkItemCreated = 
             NewRecruitEWLUtil.createNewRecruitWorkItem(appInfo); } 
   };
   newRecruitContainer.add(newRecruitEWLButton);
   newRecruitEWLButton.add(buttonlabel);
```

Comment: Thanks martin for your response. I implemented your suggestions above, except for Component.setModelObject(...), setModelObject is not available for me, so I used setDefaultModelModelObject. However, I got error - IllegalArgumentException: A child with id 'xxxxxxxxx' already exists. I'm guessing because I used the same wicket id for the AjaxLink and the Label??? I did that because you mentioned that's the component I will be updating and there is no need to create a new label inside the onClick??? please advice. Thanks.

Comment: 1) `setDefaultModelModelObject` - you use Wicket 1.4 or older.  2) `A child with id 'xxxxxxxxx'` - what exactly is `xxxxxxxx` ? The id of the AjaxLink is 'xyzButton', and the id for the label is 'clickMe' ? Or maybe you wanted the initial value of the Label to be 'clickMe' ?! You need to update your question with the HTML part for these components to make it more clear.

Comment: Please update the question. Code in the comments is not readable.

Answer (score 0):

using a div for the button label in the html file instead of a span works, and calling this method from the onclick setDefaultModel(); this method does not work in this sceanario - setDefaultModelModelObject()